Immutable function argument changes immediately after being passed in
I'm using Rust to program an arduino nano (atmega328p), and I ran into a bizarre issue while debugging why a segment of an LED display wasn't being lit. The display is represented as a byte buffer, which is set by reading from lookup tables - one for digits 0-9 and one for the letters n, u, m (nano, micro, milli). The latter is defined:
const UNIT_PATTERNS: [u8; 4] = [
    0b01010100, // n
    0b00011100, // u
    0b11010100, // m
    0b00000000  // none
];

Specifically note 'm' has the MSB set corresponding to the downstroke in the middle differentiating it from 'n'. This is what doesn't display. I found out precisely where the issue is, but I don't understand it. Here's the function where the digits and unit are set:
fn display_inductance(l: u64, serial: &mut impl ufmt::uWrite) {
    let (mut l, unit) = match l {
        0..=9999              => (l, 0),
        10000..=9999999       => (l/1000, 1),
        10000000..=9999999999 => (l/1000000, 2),
        _                     => (l/1000000000, 3)
    };

    // Interrupts are disabled within this block
    interrupt::free(|cs| {
        let mut state = DISPLAY_STATE.borrow(cs).borrow_mut();
        let state = state.as_mut().unwrap(); // contains the display byte buffer

        for i in (0..4).rev() {
            let digit = (l%10) as usize;

            set_digit(&mut state.buffer, i, DIGIT_PATTERNS[digit], serial);

            l /= 10;
        }

        ufmt::uwriteln!(serial, "Unit pattern = 0x{:x}", UNIT_PATTERNS[unit]);
        set_digit(&mut state.buffer, 4, UNIT_PATTERNS[unit], serial);
    });
}

The problem at hand concerns the last 2 lines - the debug print, and the set_digit call.
The serial link is only used to send debug info over USB, and here that's the pattern of the unit to be displayed, in hex. The global display state is accessed in an interrupt-free closure, and it contains the byte buffer mentioned earlier.
Here's the set_digit function:
fn set_digit(buffer: &mut [u8], index: usize, pattern: u8, serial: &mut impl ufmt::uWrite) {
    ufmt::uwriteln!(serial, "Setting digit {} with pattern 0x{:x}", index, pattern);
    
    let mask: u8 = 1 << index;

    for row in 0..8 {
        if pattern & (1 << row) > 0 { buffer[row] |= mask; }
        else { buffer[row] &= !mask; }
    }
}

Before anything else is done, the unit pattern is sent over serial again. The serial messages are probably just waiting in a buffer at this point assuming the serial is interrupt-driven.
In any case, the unit pattern is printed right before the set_digit call, and then again immediately inside the function. This is what I see over serial:
Unit pattern = 0xd4
Setting digit 4 with pattern 0x54

It appears the MSB has been lost in transit. Various other debug info comes back over serial, and none of it shows any sign that serial messages are being corrupted or confused. These messages also line up perfectly with the observed issue.
I've ruled out some possibilities:

The set_digit function does work. If I force pattern to 0xd4 inside it, then the buffer is written correctly and the missing segment lights.
RAM usage is not too high. It's not even half of the 2 KB the nano has.
Interrupts can't be interfering because this part happens in an interrupt-free section.
The UNIT_PATTERNS lookup table is not being modified. The serial communication repeats indefinitely, and every time it gets to this part, it always shows 0xd4 first, and 0x54 only for the second.
I'm not doing anything unsafe that should be causing issues. There is exactly one unsafe function I call, interrupt::enable() once I've set up my peripherals (display buffer is not a memory mapped peripheral - it's my own array). The safety requirements of this function are simply not to call it from within an interrupt::free section, and I never do that.

Changing certain things fixes the problem, but it's not clear why. For instance, if I have the match statement do the lookup and return UNIT_PATTERNS[n] rather than n itself, it works. However, putting a quick let pattern = UNIT_PATTERNS[unit]; right before the debug print and using that as the argument to both does not work. In other words, even with both the first debug print and the set_digit call drawing from the same non-mutable variable, I can still see 0xd4 then 0x54.
The only thing I can think of is an unlucky dead bit in RAM that this bit of code hits when everything is in the exact right (wrong) place.

Smells like UB.  Look carefully at every bit of unsafe code in your program.

Also not sure how interrupt::free can work over a closure that performs I/O.  Surely that will necessarily involve some interrupts?

Shouldn't writing to the display be volatile? And certainly not a reference.

interrupt::free internally just disables the global interrupt flag for the closure. The hardware serial only holds 2 transmit bytes, so it is almost certainly true that messages are buffered somewhere else and won't be sent until interrupts reenable.

@ChayimFriedman Ah fair point, though the issue doesn't concern the display buffer itself, which appears to work fine. The issue is just with this function parameter appearing to mutate consistently, even with no buffer accesses between the 2 debug prints
EDIT: Actually the display buffer isn't a mmapped peripheral, it's written and read purely by me - volatility shouldn't be an issue?

If it's only accessed by you how does the hardware sees it? And if there's UB there, it might as well affect your code.

This could be a miscompilation (AVR is not as common and tested as ARM or x86), or it could be a soundness issue in one of your dependencies. I think the best way to proceed from here is to inspect the assembly.

There's a timer routine that reads from the buffer and sets some IO pins accordingly. It'll only start running again once out of the interrupt-free section
I'll try to examine the assembly, thank you

If you have another Arduino board available, might be worth testing on that to eliminate a HW issue. Or failing that perhaps an emulator (maybe this? https://wokwi.com/)

With such a target, your first stop in debugging is the assembler listing, as ChayimFriedman suggests. Please add the relevant parts by [edit]ing your question, if you don't know how to interpret that.
